# Neural Network Worse than Expected on Simple Input

Tags: neural-network, keras, training-data

I have inputs that are binary (0,1) and outputs that are binary (0,1). More than 80% of the time, the binary input is equal to the binary output. However, when I train a keras neural network I get an accuracy that goes to .6. There are 1000 such inputs. Here is the network setup in Keras:

```
model = Sequential()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=1, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

This seems very strange. What could the problem be?

Comment: Well... what about starting with a NN which does **classification** instead of regression. Use binary-crossentropy loss. (Apart from that, your question is also missing additional information.)

Comment: I was originally using binary-crossentropy-loss but was experimenting with the params before posting this. What additional information am I missing?